# FillRecatangle set Opacity?

Tags: java, swing

I have a game with a [HUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-up_display_(gaming)) which is drawn by `fillrectangle`.

How would I fade these rectangles when the player is on the HUD?

Comment: What do you mean by fade?  Do you want the objects to retain a specific opacity?  Or do you want the fillrectangle to visually fade out in a specified amount of time?

Comment: Stack overflow question with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110975/how-to-make-a-rectangle-in-graphics-in-a-transparent-colour

Answer (score 1):

You can start a new thread, create a loop inside, and invoke this every few ms:

```
// decalre a golbal int i
i = (i + 1) % 0xFF
Color color = new Color(i, [your color], [your color], [your color]);
g.setColor(myColour); // graphics context object
```

And you'll see your canvas fading.